# MySQL Left Join Single Field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Currently I am joining the 'articles' table with 'users' table. Instead of joining all fields from the 'users' table, I just want to join the field 'fullName'.

Is this possible? I've been searching for a solution but haven't had much luck. This is my SQL statment currently:

```
SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN users ON articles.uid=users.uid
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show `desc articles;` and `desc users;`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Why? That's not required

Comment: Confused. I thought the ON clause was being switched from uid to fullName. Never mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change `*` to the list of wanted columns

```
SELECT 
    articles.*, 
    users.fullName 
FROM 
    articles 
LEFT JOIN users ON articles.uid=users.uid
```